# Vue's reactivity not triggered when using Bootstrap 5's alert div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Vue's reactivity not triggered when using Bootstrap 5's alert div.

See my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
        v-if="alertICDMsg!==''"
        id="alertICDCode"
        class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert"
        >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb" />
        <strong> Note!</strong> <span v-html="alertICDMsg" />
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="alert"
            aria-label="Close"
        />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input
            id="ICDCode"
            v-model="editing_icdCode"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="ICD Code"
            aria-label="ICD Code"
            @input="ICDCodeSearchRequested"
            >
        </div>
        <input
            id="Diagnosis"
            v-model="editing_diagnosis"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Diagnosis"
            aria-label="Diagnosis"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
            list="icdsearchlist"
            @change="SelectedDiagnosisTextOption"
            @input="ICDTextSearchRequested"
        >
        <datalist id="icdsearchlist">
            <option
            v-for="(disease_option, index) in icd_diagnosis_options"
            :key="index"
            >
            {{ disease_option }}
            </option>
        </datalist>
        <button
            id="btnAddDiagnoses"
            href="#"
            class="btn btn-primary mx-1"
            @click="AddDiagnosis"
        >
            <i class="fal fa-plus-circle" />
        </button>
        <button
            id="btnCopyPreviousDiagnoses"
            href="#"
            class="btn btn-primary BtnSaveGroup mx-1"
        >
            <i class="far fa-history" />
        </button>
        <button
            id="quickbill"
            class="btn btn-primary mx-1"
        >
            <i class="fas fa-search-plus" />
        </button>
        <button
            id="clearICD"
            class="btn btn-danger mx-1"
            @click="ClearICDFields"
        >
            <i class="fad fa-times-circle" />
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
<template>

<script>
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            alertICDMsg:"",
        };
    },
    watch: {
        alertICDMsg: {
            handler(val) {
            console.log(`Val for alertICDMsg changed to :${val}`);
            },
            immediate: true,
            deep: true,
        },
    },
    methods: {
        ICDCodeSearchRequested() {
            console.log(`Search by ICD code`);
            this.alertICDMsg="Searching in ICD Code box will search only by code. To search by a diagnosis name, type in the Diagnosis box."
            console.log(`alertICDMsg is ${this.alertICDMsg}`);
            setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(`Dismissing alert`); 
            this.alertICDMsg=''; 
            console.log(`alertICDMsg is ${this.alertICDMsg}`);
            }, 5000);
        },
    },
    }
</script>
```

Console log:

```
Search by ICD code
SubClinicalBlock.vue?d801:291 alertICDMsg is Searching in ICD Code box will search only by code. To search by a diagnosis name, type in the Diagnosis box.
SubClinicalBlock.vue?d801:220 Val for alertICDMsg changed to :Searching in ICD Code box will search only by code. To search by a diagnosis name, type in the Diagnosis box.
SubClinicalBlock.vue?d801:293 Dismissing alert
SubClinicalBlock.vue?d801:298 alertICDMsg is
```

The problem is that after 5 seconds, though the value of the variable changes, the alert is still visible.

I checked some similiar questions, and have seen this happening when bootstrap's javascript wasnt loaded. But for me, Bootstrap v5.0.1 JS is being loaded from the CDN and appears in the sources tab in Chrome.

Comment: Try to change the function inside of setTimeout to arrow function like `setTimeout(() => { // code here })`. Maybe the `this` inside the function reference to the wrong context inside of the function instead of the vue component.

Comment: @Andy That was it! Can you make this an answer?

Comment: Added the answer and reference doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the function inside of setTimeout to arrow function like this

```js
setTimeout(() => { // code here })
```

The `this` inside of `setTimeout(function () => {})` reference to the wrong context (the function itself) instead of the Vue component.

The arrow function doesn't have the `this` binding so when you use the arrow function the `this` keyword will reference the Vue component and change the state.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions